# background-image load 404, can't see why

Tags: css, image, browser, http-status-code-404

I get a 404 for one image but not another, both loaded as background-images in a stylesheet, all on the same page & domain. It used to work but now doesn't, change is browser, i.e. Opera Desktop to Google Chrome mobile, both on Win10.

Works:

```
.fleuron {
    height: 2.5em;
    background-image: url(eDowserFleuron.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: 21px 21px;
}
```

doesn't work:

```
.header {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    background-color: #5fc6e8;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 16pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-bottom: 1px #5fbce8 outset;
    background-image: url(eDowserLogo.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 14px 0px;
    background-size: 30px 30px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    /* padding-top: 1px; */
    padding-right: 14px;
    /* overflow: auto; */
}
```

I can't see a difference.

Comment: make sure your images are in static folder of your project like `/public/images` and use relative urls like `background-image: url('/image/eDowserLogo.png');`

Answer (score 0):

It's more possible that the problem is not in the code, but the pathing. In case you copy-pasted your files in another folder, it is most likely that you're still working with the **old** ones.

Open up your code editor, close all the tabs, and reopen them from the directory you're working in. I'm pretty sure that you will find your code isn't changed.

If that doesn't solve it, make sure your pathing is correct (I suppose you're experienced enough to be able to track it well).

Third case may be the code. First, add **" "** to the **url()** so it looks like this:

`url("image-path/image_name.png")`.

If any of these don't solve anything, last thing to do is to start commenting all your css except the `background-image: url(eDowserLogo.png);` and tick them off until you find which one is causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks all. Haven't got anywhere. It isn't paths. Sometimes one image gets found but isn't clear why. Re-saving in GIMP doesn't achieve anything. Really don't like non-rational bugs.

Comment: in that case, do something simple like copying all the files to another location and running from there. you might know that systems cometimes just get weird, and can't explain why they are acting the way they do, so we just restart them in one way or another :D

Comment: I tried renaming all the files names starting "eD*" to "d*", and it came to life! Great minds think alike. I still have a bug with some not being visible, which the F12 debugger can fix. Need to make that always. So chrome doesn't like mixed case file names, who knew?

Comment: beautiful, glad to have been of help! keep it up m8